# How do I select the first value that meets or exceeds some criterion?

Tags: sql, max

I have a table that contains the salary schedule of employees. I want when searching for a specific salary, that salary is selected and if it doesn't  exist, the next closest greater salary is selected.

Example: I am looking for a salary of 5,200. If it exists, it is selected. Iif it does not exist, the salary above it is selected, for example 5300.

I tried to use this but it gave me the max value and I want the next greater value :

```
SELECT MAX(sal) FROM tst WHERE sal >= 5900 LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could order the query so that the first row found satisfied the requirement:

```sql
SELECT sal 
FROM tst 
WHERE sal >= 5950
ORDER BY sal
LIMIT 1
```